# ZF2 Accessing routes and posts via a factory

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to access a route and post via a form factory. The route or the post contains an ID which I need to inject into my form so that I can build a select statement.

Currently I am injecting into the form via the controller using

```
$this->MyForm->get('elementName')->setOptions(array('value_options' =>$myArrayOfOptions));
```

My goal is to keep the business logic out of the controller hence why I am keen to use the formFactory instead however I do need access to the ID in the post or route to achieve this.

My Form Factory looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace MyModule\Form;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use AdminLottery\InputFilter\MyFilter;
use AdminLottery\Service\MyService;

     class MyFormFactory implements FactoryInterface
     {
        /**
         * Create service
         *
         * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
         * @return mixed
        */
        public function createService(
            ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
        )
        {
            //$serviceLocator is FormElementManager
            $realSL = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();

            //*** I NEED TO ACCESS THE ID / POST HERE TO SEND TO MY FORM

            return new MyForm(
                $realSL->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'),
                $realSL->get('InputFilterManager')->get(MyFilter::class),
                $realSL,
                $realSL->get(MyService::class)
            );
        }
    }
```

Any Ideas??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the request instance

**MyFormFactory**

```
//...
$request = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('Request');

$id = $request->getPost('id', false);

if ($id) $form->setOption('id', $id);

//...
```

**Edit:** This is very similar to [another question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953346/how-to-pass-options-params-to-formcollection-fieldset-in-zendframework-2/23955227#23955227)

**Edit 2**

In your factory can access the *route* params via the router's `Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch`.

```
$request = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('Request');
$router  = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('Router');
$match   = $router->match($request); // \Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch

$id = ($match) ? $match->getParam('id', false) : false;  

if ($id) $form->setOption('id', $id); //....
```

Comment: Ahh, that is half the battle won. Thank you for that. So getPost takes care of a post action, what takes place of a $_GET['id'] action?

Comment: You have access to the [`Zend/Http/Request`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/Request.php) so you can do `$request->getQuery('id')` etc

Comment: Brilliant, this is what I have been searching for. Thank you!!

Comment: Noticed getRequest() does not grab the ID from the url: myroute/path/id/1 however getRequestUri() returns "myroute/path/id/1". I am assuming I will have to strip the ID out of the string in the absence of a better method? Unless my ZF@ framework version needs to be updated...

Comment: @HappyCoder The request object is a wrapper for `$_GET` and `$_POST` etc So you wont't get the route params there. You can access them via the `Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Params` controller plugin which would just be used as `$this->params()->fromRoute('id')` from within the controller. That plugin is simply a convienace plugin for the longer: `$controller->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('id')`.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this via the factory? That is where I need the ID from the route to inject into the form...

Comment: hmm getting odd error: Call to undefined method Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack::getRouteMatch()

Comment: Updated to this: $router = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('Router'); although error persists

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for a reference, I thought I would add the final code I used:

**Semi-final code::**

```
    $router = $realSL->get('Router');
    $request = $realSL->get('Request');
    $routeMatch = $router->match($request);
    $matchArray  = $routeMatch->getParams();
    if (isset($matchArray['id'])) {
        $id = (int) $matchArray['id'];
    }  else {
        $id = 0;
    }
```

**Final code::**

```
$realSL->get('application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('id', 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for a controller factory, that would work in the same manner for any other factory:

```
namespace MyModule\Controller\Factory;

use MyModule\Controller\MyController;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class MyControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        /*
         * @var Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager
         */
        $realServiceLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        ...
        $router = $realServiceLocator->get('router');
        $request = $realServiceLocator->get('request');
        $routerMatch = $router->match($request);
        ...
        $test1 = $routerMatch->getParams();
        $test2 = $request->getQuery();
        $test3 = $request->getPost();
        ...
        return new MyController(...);
    }
}
```